# AngularJS nested ng-repeat access $parent array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Right so I have a dilemma, that seems like a simple question but I can't figure it out.

I have a nested array:

```
$scope.rootItem = {
        id: '1',
        type: 'course',
        title: 'Adobe Photoshop CC for beginners',
        items: [{
            id: '2',
            type: 'label',
            title:'Label Title',
            items:[{
                id: '3',
                type: 'module',
                title:'Module title',
                items: [{
                    id: '4',
                    type: 'topic',
                    title:'Topic title',
                    items: [{
                        id: '5',
                        type: 'content',
                        title:'Content title'
                    }, {
                        id: '6',
                        type: 'content',
                        title:'Content title'
                    }]
                }]
            },{
                id: '7',
                type: 'resources',
                title:'Resources'
            },{
                id: '8',
                type: 'module',
                title:'Module title',
                items: [{
                    id: '9',
                    type: 'topic',
                    title:'Topic',
                    items: [{
                        id: '10',
                        type: 'question',
                        title:'Question title'
                    }]
                }, {
                    id: '11',
                    type: 'topic',
                    title:'Topic title',
                    items: [{
                        id: '12',
                        type: 'content',
                        title:'Content title'
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        },{
            id: '14',
            type: 'assessmentLabel',
            title: 'Assessment Label',
            items: [{
                id: '15',
                type: 'assessment',
                title: 'Assessment Title',
                items: [{
                    id: '16',
                    type: 'courseAssessment',
                    title: 'Course Assessment Question',
                    items: []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    };
```

That is outputted using ng-repeat. All works great there, by the way it is also sortable using ng-sortable (based on JQuery UI Sortable).

What I'm trying to do is duplicate lets say id: 5 using `angular.copy()`.

HTML:

```
<a href="" title="Duplicate Content" data-ng-click="duplicate(ngModelItem, $parent.ngModelItem.items)">
<span class="icon-duplicate"></span>
</a>
```

That seems to work fine too. I'm able to pass the object to the function.

The problem arises when I try and push that object to its parents array. I read about $parent and what I think would make sense is passing `$parent.ngModelItems.items` to the ng-click as such:

```
data-ng-click="duplicate(ngModelItem, $parent.ngModelItem.items)"
```

Which to me makes sense, pass parents ngModelItem.items (items is array that ID:5 is part of). But I can't figure out why do I get $parent.ngModelItem.items as undefined.

This is my controller:

```
$scope.duplicate = function(item, parent) {
        var itemCopy = angular.copy(item);

        parent.push(item);
    };
```

HTML ng-repeat:

```
<ul class="apps-container" ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="ngModelItem.items" ng-class="ngModelItem.type">
            <li class="innerCont" ng-repeat="innerItem in ngModelItem.items">
                <tg-dynamic-directive ng-model="innerItem" tg-dynamic-directive-view="getView">
                </tg-dynamic-directive>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

But angular seems to have different ideas. So I guess my question is how can I pass parents ngModelItem.items (rootItem.items) so that I can access that array?

**Can someone please explain why** `{{$parent.$parent.ngModelItems.id}}` returns correct parent id. **Yet when I try to pass that parent to the function** such as

```
data-ng-click="duplicate(parent.parent.ngModelItem.items)"
```

It doesnt work

Directive below:

```
angular.module('tg.dynamicDirective', [])
    .directive('tgDynamicDirective', ['$compile',
        function($compile) {
            'use strict';

            function templateUrlProvider(getView, ngModelItem) {
                if (getView) {
                    if (typeof getView === 'function') {
                        var templateUrl = getView(ngModelItem) || '';
                        if (templateUrl) {
                            return templateUrl;
                        }
                    } else if (typeof getView === 'string' && getView.length) {
                        return getView;
                    }
                }
                return '';
            }

            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                require: '^ngModel',
                scope: true,
                template: '<div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                    scope.$watch(function() {
                        var ngModelItem = scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel);
                        var getView = scope.$eval(attrs.tgDynamicDirectiveView);
                        scope.ngModelItem = ngModelItem;
                        return templateUrlProvider(getView, ngModelItem);
                    }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                        scope.templateUrl = newValue;
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle showcasing your problem

Comment: Hey Gopinath its very complex to recreate in a fiddle. :(

Comment: I asked fiddle because I couldn't able to see your code of "ng-repeat" in the above question. Can you paste all necessary code which can be used to reflect your problem

Comment: Ok, sure no problem at all, 1 second

Comment: mention your directive code, some problem in directive scoping probably.

Comment: Directive is there now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few hours of trying to fix this, and reading numerous articles about `$scope` inheritance I found out that ng-if create new scope using prototypical inheritance. Which I was not accounting for.

Which required me to insert one more $parent when passing it to the function as such:

```
 data-ng-click="duplicate(ngModelItem, $parent.$parent.$parent.ngModelItem)"
```

and then in the controller do something like this:

```
$scope.duplicate = function(item, parent) {
        var itemCopy = angular.copy(item);
        var parentArray = parent.items;
        parentArray.push(itemCopy)
    };
```

Hope this will save someone hours of work, whoever runs into this problem.

Comment: I had $parent.$parent and something must have updated. Adding the third $parent did the trick.